# Check if a list exists in my database by querySet django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'd like to verify if a list of variables exist in my database
I tried this:

```
if Magazine.objects.filter(mag=post.mag_no, prodc_magt_no__in[post.cn1,post.cn2,post.cn3,post.cn4)
```

but this queryset is check at least one value, I wanna check the whole `list:post.cn1,post.cn2,post.cn3,post.cn4` in my database `column = prodc_magt_no`

My database

```
ID     WORK_YMD    LINE_NM  MODEL_CODE    MAG_NO             PRODC_MAGT_NO 
    118002  20191015    PBA-21F BN94-14806W A656MAF00001    BR10BN9414806WA656MAE4035
    118003  20191015    PBA-21F BN94-14806W A656MAF00001    BR10BN9414806WA656MAE4027
    118004  20191015    PBA-21F BN94-14806W A656MAF00001    BR10BN9414806WA656MAE4039
    118005  20191015    PBA-21F BN94-14806W A656MAF00001    BR10BN9414806WA656MAE4037
    118006  20191015    PBA-21F BN94-14806W A656MAF00001    BR10BN9414806WA656MAE4038
```

note: `mag=post.mag_no` is necessary!

Comment: What type of field is `prodc_magt_no`?

Comment: I updated this information, this is my database column

Comment: Maybe it's a matter of calling .count() on the queryset, and checking that it's the correct amount. Depending on whether the mag_no/prodc_magt_no combinations are unique.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way I used was IF/ELSE statement

```
if not  Magazine.objects.filter(mag_no=post.mag_no, prodc_magt_no__in=[post.cn1]):
        messages.warning(request,'CN1 NG')

elif not  Magazine.objects.filter(mag_no=post.mag_no, prodc_magt_no__in=[post.cn2]):
    messages.warning(request,'CN2 NG')

elif not  Magazine.objects.filter(mag_no=post.mag_no, prodc_magt_no__in=[post.cn3]):
    messages.warning(request,'CN3 NG')

elif not  Magazine.objects.filter(mag_no=post.mag_no, prodc_magt_no__in=[post.cn4]):
    messages.warning(request,'CN4 NG')

elif not (post.cn1 == post.cn2, post.cn2 == post.cn3, post.cn3 == post.cn4):
    form.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Success saved')
    return redirect('CnCheckList')

else:
    messages.error(request, 'CNs already exist or invalid')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it was just a copy-paste issue, but the line of code is not valid. It's missing an `=` operator and properly enclosing the list. Without seeing the actual models, in theory this would work:

```
if Magazine.objects.filter(mag=post.mag_no, prodc_magt_no__in=[post.cn1,post.cn2,post.cn3,post.cn4]).exists()
```

exists() will check if there is at least one entry from that filter, it won't tell you how many. As suggested in a comment, count() could do that for you.

Comment: It was a copy issue, I tried exists() as you recommended, but I wanna check if the 4 itens exist in the list, only one is not enough